# Bar plotting speed in R

Tags: r, graphics, charts

Is there any way to speed graphics (bar plot) in R.  I'm on Win XP and it is painfully sloooooooow even for charts with only 4 bars!  I also tried using gplots library but it has the same speed performance problem.

This script takes 12 minutes to draw a simple bar chart :

```
library(gplots)
graphics.off()       # Close graphics windows  

counts <- c(312676, 256218, 244562, 233332)
letters <- c("E", "A", "I", "S")

windows()

barplot2(
    counts, 
    main=c("Distribution des mots par lettre"), 
    ylab= "Compte",
    names.arg=letters, 
    density=counts, 
    beside=TRUE, 
    col=rainbow(5)
)
```

Comment: Simply put: I don't believe you. (I've never had any speed problems with bar plots.) But I could be convinced with a reproducible example!

Comment: This script takes 12 minutes to draw a simple bar chart!

library(gplots)
rm(list = ls())      # Clear all variables  
graphics.off()       # Close graphics windows  

counts <- c(312676, 256218, 244562, 233332)
letters <- c("E", "A", "I", "S")

windows()

barplot2(
 counts, 
 main=c("Distribution des mots par lettre"), 
 ylab= "Compte",
 names.arg=letters, 
 density=counts, 
 beside=TRUE, 
 col=rainbow(5)
)

Comment: I was just about to post the answer that appeared below, but I was also going to include these notes: (1) Never put code in comments; edit it into your question. (2) I can find no function called `windows()`, in any package. (3) Never give people scripts with `rm(list = ls())`, that's mean. Trust them to start a new session.

Comment: Sorry joran!  This is my first question here and I'm not familiar with the rules yet!

Comment: No worries! Just trying to get you up to speed...

Comment: @joran try getAnywhere(windows) for me, that located a function by that name in grDevices. Also, unless this is just a built-in part of the gplots() package of which I was unaware, I did notice that the plot opened in a new window for me as opposed to in the frame to which I allocate graphing (I use RStudio)

Comment: @psychometriko I think now that it must be platform specific because I still don't see it; maybe Windows only?

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. If the other half of my computer weren't fried I would switch over and check it out now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're providing the argument

```
density=counts
```

From the help manual for that function:

density
a vector giving the the density of shading lines, in lines per inch, for the bars or bar components. The default value of NULL means that no shading lines are drawn. Non-positive values of density also inhibit the drawing of shading lines.

It looks like you are trying to draw several hundreds of thousands of lines per inch.

Comment: Exactly!  Solved.  Many thanks!